# FreeBSD: IPv6 in Jails (ezjail)

Tags: freebsd, ipv6, jails

I'm on FreeBSD 10.1 and in the process of setting up a server.
After some hassle I managed to get IPv6 running.

I'm now setting up jails with `ezjail` and I learned how to set up a working flavor and a jail with IPv4 internet access.

However, I can't get IPv6 to work in the jail and I have no idea why.

My lo0 interface in the jail doesn't get a IPv6 address.

What am I missing?

`/etc/rc.conf`

```
[…]
gateway_enable="YES"
ipv6_gateway_enable="YES"
[…]
```

`/usr/local/etc/ezjail/test`

```
[…]
export jail_test_ip="lo0|10.0.0.2,lo0|fe80::2"
[…]
```

`ifconfig`

```
[…]
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=600003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x2 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet 10.0.0.2 netmask 0xffffffff 
    inet6 fe80::2%lo0 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x2 
    nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
[…]
```

Jail `ifconfig`

```
[…]
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=600003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
    inet 10.0.0.2 netmask 0xffffffff 
    nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
[…]
```

Answer (score 1):

in server rc.conf is:

```
ifconfig_re0_ipv6="inet6 accept_rtadv"
```

(You can add a static ipv6 address if you like)
In my environment my router gives IPv6 adresses to other systems.

`ifconfig` on the server itself:

```
re0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
This is the server ip config
         ether 22:22:22:22:22:22
         inet6 fe80::1ae1:b1ff:fe11:1234%re0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
         inet 172.16.0.200 netmask 0xffffffff broadcast 172.16.0.200
         inet6 2001:123:4567:0:1234:1234:1234:1234 prefixlen 64 autoconf
         inet 172.16.0.20 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 172.16.0.255
         nd6 options=23<PERFORMNUD,ACCEPT_RTADV,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
         media: Ethernet autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
         status: active
```

Now, configure in: `/usr/local/etc/ezjail/anysystem`:

```
export jail_proxy_ip="172.16.0.200,2001:123:1234:0:1234:1234:1234:1234"
```

(without any blank after the comma)

Restart this jail, go to jail console and run `ifconfig`. You will see one ipv4 and one ipv6 address.

```
uname -a:
FreeBSD 10.2-RELEASE r286666
```

I have tested this with a squid jail and it works fine.